# Microsoft Access Sub Form Write Conflict Troubles

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, conflict

I have a form which contains a subform which displays editable fields linked to one my tables. For a project I'm currently working on, one of the requirements is that I have to track when the last change was made to a record and who did so.

So what I've done is for each editable textbox or combobox within the form and subform I've made it so they have events on their `BeforeUpdate` and `AfterUpdate` events.

For example my BeforeUpdate for a textbox:

```
Private Sub textbox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not isValidUser Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.textbox.Undo
    End If
End Sub
```

and my AfterUpdate is:

```
Private Sub textbox_AfterUpdate()
    updateRecord Me.textbox.Value, UserNameWindows
End Sub
```

and updateRecord is:

```
Public Sub updateRecord(bucNumber As String, updater As String)

    Dim Dbs As Object
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim fldEnumerator As Object
    Dim fldColumns As Object

    sqlStatement = "SELECT fName " & _
                        "FROM t_Staff " & _
                        "WHERE uName='" & updater & "';"

    'Getting fullname of user via username
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlStatement)

    'Setting fullname to updater variable
    updater = rst(0)

    'Clean Up
    Set rst = Nothing

    'Opening Bucket Contents
    Set Dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = Dbs.OpenRecordset("Bucket Contents")
    Set fldColumns = rst.Fields

    'Scan the records from beginning to each
    While Not rst.EOF
        'Check the current column
    For Each fldEnumerator In rst.Fields
        'If the column is named Bucket No
        If fldEnumerator.Name = "Bucket No" Then
            'If the Bucket No of the current record is the same as bucketNumber
                If fldEnumerator.Value = bucNumber Then
                    'Then change the updated fields by updater and todays date
                    rst.Edit
                    rst("Last Updated By").Value = updater
                    rst("Last Updated On").Value = Date
                    rst.Update
                End If
            End If
        Next
        'Move to the next record and continue the same approach
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend

    'Clean Up
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set Dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Okay now is the weird thing, this works totally fine when I make a modification to a control within the Main form, however as soon as a try to alter something in the subform it throws up a write conflict.

If I opt to save record it ignores my code for updating who last modified it and when and if I opt to discard the change it runs my code and updates it that it has been changed!

Anyone know what is wrong or of a better way to do this?

Comment: As soon as you move from form to subform and vice versa, the record is saved, so any update events will run. You might like to look at the links in the comments to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131134/audit-track-a-subform-within-a-form. For the most part, I include CreatedDate, CreatedBy, LastUpdatedDate, LastUpdatedBy fields in every user editable table.

Comment: I don't believe I'm moving from the subfrom to the main form? I've taken a look at that method of conducting an Audit and may switch to that if this doesn't pan out.